# I installed EdrawMax and can't uninstall it from the terminal

Tags: uninstall, software-uninstall

I recently installed this drawing program from its homepage (https://www.edrawsoft.com/download-edrawmax-linux.php here is the link). Now I no longer want it on my computer, but the application does not appear listed when I look for it using the `dpkg --list` command on the terminal; therefore, when I try to remove it using `apt-get`, it just says that it can't locate the package (I type `sudo apt-get remove edrawmax`, because `edrawmax` is the command with which you execute the program from the terminal, but this is evidently not the correct thing to do). I found where the directory of this application is located (it is located in "/opt"), but I do not dare to just delete all the files. What should i do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the installation, the program is installed on
*/otp/EdrawMax-9-64* (depends of program version - in this case v9 64bit)
The "Official program uninstallation" is actualy deleting of the folders:

Deleting the Main Program:

```
rm -rf /opt/EdrawMax-9-64/
```

Deleting the rest of the program (icons, Launcher, etc.)

```
rm -f /usr/share/icons/edrawmax.png
rm -f /usr/share/applications/edrawmax.desktop
rm -f /usr/share/mime/packages/edrawmax.xml
rm -f /usr/share/icons/gnome/scalable/mimetypes/eddx.svg
rm -f /usr/local/bin/edrawmax
```

Edit:
Deleting files from home dir

```
sudo rm -r $HOME/Edraw
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **:-)** Please [edit] and explain what your commands do and also add an `rm` for the config file.  **;-)**